# Vertical alignment - Firefox

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

It works in every browser, except firefox. The size of image is not fixed. I need to center vertically any image inside `<a>` tag.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="tip popup">
    <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-IjgG5GYb7SI/UNyqFqIOHkI/AAAAAAAAEd8/aoWhNyoSYiw/s1600/Toshiba+Lightfield+Module+AJ201212270055.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.tip img {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}   

.tip {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -14px;
    margin-left: -14px;
    padding-right: 28px;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pbe7m/3/

Comment: Would it be okay to make the image a background? or will the image have inherent semantic value?

Answer (score 0):

Try to give to an image:

```
img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0;
}
```